# Solving these types of integrals, using Monotone convergence theorem and Dominated convergence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm allowed to use these two theories and obviously the standard techniques when solving integrals.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \int_{0}^{1}\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}} x \ln x}{1+n^2x^2}dx$$

I did a similar looking integral in class using the conditions of the Dominated convergence theorem setting $f_n(x)=\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}} x \ln x}{1+n^2x^2}$ and finding $g(x)>|f_n(x)|$ as $n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}x},$ by finding the extremum of $f_n(x)$ in respect to $n$ meaning I took $f_n(x)$ as a function of $n: m_x(n)=\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}} x \ln x}{1+n^2x^2}.$ so $g(x)=m_x(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}x})$

then finding out that $$\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx$$ isn't solvable, so I can't use the dominated convergence theorem this way? Any ideas? Is there another way to solve this definite integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x \log x$ is bounded between 0 and $-1/e$ on $[0,1]$.  Write
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{n} x \log x}{1 + n^2 x^2} dx = \left(\int_0^{n^{-2/3}} + \int_{n^{-2/3}}^1\right) \frac{\sqrt{n} x \log x}{1 + n^2 x^2} dx.
$$
On $[0, n^{-2/3}]$, $|x \log x| \leq \frac23 n^{-2/3} \log n$ and $1 + n^2 x^2 \geq 1$, so
$$
\int_0^{n^{-2/3}} \frac{\sqrt{n} x \log x}{1 + n^2 x^2} dx \leq
\int_0^{n^{-2/3}} \frac23 n^{-1/6} \log n dx.
$$
This tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.
On $[n^{-2/3}, 1]$, $|x \log x| \leq 1/e$ and $1 + n^2 x^2 \geq n^{2/3}$, so
$$
\int_{n^{-2/3}}^1 \frac{\sqrt{n} x \log x}{1 + n^2 x^2} dx \leq
\int_{n^{-2/3}}^1 \frac{\sqrt{n}}{e n^{2/3}} dx \leq \int_{n^{-2/3}}^1 \frac{n^{-1/6}}{e} dx.
$$
This also tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{n^{\frac12}x\log(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=n^{-\frac32}\int_0^n\frac{x(\log(x)-\log(n))}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac12n^{-\frac32}\int_0^n(\log(x)-\log(n))\,\mathrm{d}\log\left(1+x^2\right)\tag{2}\\
&=-\frac12n^{-\frac32}\int_0^n\frac{\log\left(1+x^2\right)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=-n^{-\frac32}\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&-n^{-\frac32}\int_1^n\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}\right)+\log(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac xn$
$(2)$: prepare to integrate by parts
$(3)$: integrate by parts
$(4)$: break integral into pieces

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^1\frac{\frac12x^2}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac14\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^n\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}\right)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac1{2x^2}}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac14\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\int_1^n\frac{\log(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12\log(n)^2\tag{7}
$$
Combining $(4)$-$(7)$ gives
$$
-\frac12n^{-\frac32}\left(1+\log(n)^2\right)\le\int_0^1\frac{n^{\frac12}x\log(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\le0\tag{8}
$$
and the Squeeze Theorem yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{n^{\frac12}x\log(x)}{1+n^2x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{9}
$$